# Cypress not loading an updated file

Tags: cypress

Cypress is not reading my updated script. I make a change in WebStorm. Cypress starts to load the file but then refreshes and loads an old file. It does not load the updated spec. I then check the file using the Open in IDE link in Cypress and it shows me the newly updated spec. Why is Cypress loading an old file and not running the updated one?

I've updated Cypress to 4.12.0. Closed it, reopened and still it does not run the file that I have in the Integration directory. And the old file it does run is not in the Integration directory. So why is it trying to run that file. I thought Cypress only executes files in the Integration directory

Comment: Hi Larry, if you add your directory structure before and after the new file, we'll be able to more effectively help.

Comment: I deleted version 4.12 and went back to version 3.50. It now works perfectly, just like they show in the guides. Don't know what is wrong with version 4 but it doesn't work as expected in the guides.

Comment: I have the same problem with the version 7.5 ! It always loads old folders, even if I delete them and don't refresh the new one... It's weird...

Answer (score 0):

Switching back to version "^7.6.0" fixed it.